# Difference between using validation and IF clause in MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I working on a WPF application with MVVM pattern.to implementing the validation part i have two choices:

- A-Implementing IDataErrorInfo with ValidationRule
- B-Using Simple If    Statements with out any intericated thing more.

So the main question is that what the difference between them?

Comment: If you're working with .NET 4.5, you could also look into the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface. I found it has much more flexibility than these two ways.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to pay attention to here is **separation of concerns**. The ViewModel where you would have your `If` statements does not need to know how the Customer data is validated.

Also, if the class you have implementing `IDataErrorInfo` were to be used in more than one View, you'd have to repeat validation logic in that ViewModel again. IDataErrorInfo allows you to keep these concerns separate and easy to alter in the future.

Let `XAML` and the interface take care of validation and error messages, and let the ViewModel take care of using already validated data for its own ends.